# Why are my backlinks not showing on google on this asp.net website with all I've done?

Tags: google, seo

I recently implemented many SEO techniques for a company on their asp.net website; in 6 months, we jumped from a PR1 to a PR3.  But I'm having issues with google backlinking.

***Here are some of the things I've done:***

1. Not only did I set up their own Google+ page 6 months ago, I update it pretty much daily with links, pictures, etc., and I blog about it on my own personal Google+ page and post links, etc. ...
2. They have their own Twitter, Facebook, YouTube, and all are updated almost daily.
3. I've listed in as many quality, relevant directories as possible 6 months ago; I've avoided link farms.
4. The site is solid SEO-wise. Key-phrase rich URLs, schema.org & rich snippets.
5. No duplicate content ... www or non-www 301's, trailing slashes, etc.  ... all taken care of.
6. Probably a ton of other things, but basically, the site is all set, SEO-wise.

***Here's what's confounding:***

When I do a **link:www.example.com** in Bing/Yahoo, it shows **many backlinks**.  When I do a **link:www.example.com** in **google, it shows up 0 links**.  Or when I use a site-ranker like [Web Site Rank Tool](http://websiteranktool.com) it's showing 0 backlinks from Google.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-To best estimate the back-links to your website you can:

1. Register the site to Google Webmaster Tools and go to `Traffic -> Links to your site`
2. Register the site to Google Analytic and go to : `Traffic Sources -> Referrals`

It takes time to this data to appear, so be be patience :)

There are many issues using the link:DOMAIN filter, it depends on the TLD of Google website and many other factors.

Comment: Thanks YardenST ... I've done all the google webmaster tools, etc., but I appreciate your advise!

Answer (score 2):

We have a PR6 site and Google shows only 198 backlinks for our domain.

I wouldn't worry about it, Google's `Link:` feature has never been reliable or meaningful for some years.

Here's a good article by Rand Fishkin (SEO Moz) that goes into the issue in more depth:
http://www.seomoz.org/blog/google-link-command-busting-the-myths

Comment: Wow, that's a lot to digest ... but thank you for taking the time to read my question and respond.  I'll definitely parse what Matt Cutts has to say.  Thanks again Tom!

Answer (score 2):

Please read about google new update on penguin and Google envelope ,links are not so popular now as they come across spammy , as for daily updates in Smo don't do daily as google also thinks this as spam spread it out over time maybe twice a month ,and also for hard targeting keywords o rank page one google you have to wait from 3 months to one year like I had to for many sites of my own and clients sites I have been doing seo for over six years I have lots of websites I use in testing as I see for myself what's working or not , I to have sites that were page one then disappear then appear doing the google shuffle they eventually come back it's just google finding new sites and yours will go back

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, @Kane.  My site went from a PR 1, and just recently a PR 3, so Google must have updated their PR'ings.  But I'm just wondering about why link:mydomain.com isn't showing any backlinks in google. Thanks for the Panda and Penguin updates ... although just about every page is rich, quality content complete with quality youtube engineering demonstrations.  But the basic message is that Google wants you to do things, just not too many things ... hehe .... Thanks again for your time, Kane.

Answer (score 1):

Most or all of those social media sites add rel="nofollow" to all external links. And the value of links from most directories is dubious at best (not that I don't ever use them but they are suspect).

Any link that can be obtained in an automated fashion probably isn't worth having and if you are that religious about social media posts (i.e. YouTube everyday‽) you might, in the eyes of a search engine seem like a 'robot.'

A month ago (in Oct. 2012) GoogleWebmasterHelp added this video to YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chuhSmwsL7s&feature=plcp

I think very much applies to the spirit of your question. If, in the eyes of a search engine, the things you are doing seem automated you might not get much from them.

There is also the rumored 'Over Optimization Penalty.'

It sounds like you are doing the right things but perhaps trying to hard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Yarden is right . Google not always list all the back links. I had 263 back links in webmaster tools , but one fine day its showing only 63. I have more unique back links displayed in Alexa.Then i tried "SERPAttacks" ,it too show erroneous data. I am too confused .  Don't know where to look for reliable list of back links.

Comment: Hi Susan.  Thanks for responding.  I understand black hat and white hat SEO techniques, but still, many of 'em are unreliable at best.  There's a difference between rel=nofollow and rel=noindex pages.  Twitter is rel=nofollow, yet I get indexed there all the time.  As far as guestimating the number of backlinks you have out there, it's like you really just have to keep doing what you're doing.  Keep backlinking; some tools are more accurate than others.